# Как сделать две первые буквы заглавным в JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Как сделать две первые буквы заглавным в JS
У меня не получается вот код который я попробовал!!!!

```
function f(str) {
    if(!str) return str;

    return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
}

alert(f('mars'));
```

У меня получается только первая буква.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function f(str) {
    if(!str) return str;

    return str[0].toUpperCase() +
           str[1].toUpperCase() + 
           str.slice(2);
}

alert(f('mars'));
```

Только если строка может быть меньше двух символов, добавьте проверку.

Answer (score 3):

У вас возвращается срока с первой буквой в верхнем регистре, так как вы применили метод `toUpperCase()` только к первому элементу строки, а далее воспользовались конкатенацией с оставшейся частью строки.

```
function f(str) {
    return str.slice(0,2).toUpperCase() + str.slice(2).toLowerCase()
}

console.log(f('mars'));
```